# Excel Formula Nested IF AND OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am trying to get this to work and I have for the most part but missing one piece I want to add. So far I am using this

```
=IF(OR(AND(G2="Received", C2<>0),AND(G2<>"Received",C2=0)), "PASS", "FAIL")
```

What I want to happen is to add that if the item is shipped status but not received in another system but the shipment was within 1 calendar day then set the field to say review other wise if its older than one day say fail.

if `G2` is "received" and `C2` is not 0 then pass otherwise fail
if `G2` is not "received" and `C2` is 0 then pass otherwise fail
if `G2` is ""Shipped" and `C2` is not zero and `X2` less than 1 day from current date then REVIEW otherwise fail

Answer (score 1):

I would write this exactly as you have it in that last paragraph, and drop the "OR" from your original `IF` formula:

```
=IF(AND(G2="Received",C2<>0), "PASS", If(AND(G2<>"Received", C2=0), "Pass", If(AND(G2="Shipped", C2<>0), "Pass", "Fail")))
```

If it gets more complicated then that, then consider a UDF to keep your sanity in check.

Also, since each one of these three conditions is mutually exclusive, you could refactor this thing down into a boolean statement:

```
=(G2="Received")*(C2<>0) + (G2<>"Received")*(C2=0) + (G2="Shipped")*(C2<>0)
```

This will return True or False instead of Pass or Fail. It's a little shorter and doesn't rely on nested if's so adding more combinations of conditions should be easier in the future.

---

I missed that last date requirement. Updated statement:

```
    =IF(AND(G2="Received",C2<>0), "PASS", If(AND(G2<>"Received", C2=0), "Pass", If(AND(G2="Shipped", C2<>0, Today()-x2<=1), "REVIEW", "Fail")))
```

So... just added an extra condition in the last `AND()` here.

Comment: Thank you that worked as far as getting me 1 step closer with adding the shipped but I only want that to pass if the date in cell X2  is more than 1 day old, otherwise fail.   Is that possible?  so in X2 it shows "04/14/16" so that would set the field to REVIEW since it is within one calendar day of the current date?

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried quite a few things but couldn't figure it out.  As you showed me I also had an extra OR in there.  You are a lifesaver or at least a weekend saver =).  Thank you!

Comment: one more question, so because I have the line below it is changing the "Shipped" to pass even though later in the formula we tell it to set to fail or REVIEW.  I think this is because shipped is not received and therefore meets the first criteria.  I thought saying not received was the easiest way because OI have 7 different statuses.  Will I need to do 5 nested IF to cover each status rather than blanket anything that is not received so I can get the shipped part to work?  Or can we just move the shipped piece to the beginning so it does that first?  

"If(AND(G2<>"Received", C2=0), "

Comment: oh right. Yea.  Move your `=` conditions to the front of the nest and it will work better. The `<>` will sort of be your last catch all. That's a good idea. If the logic is going to get super complicated, I would highly suggest switching over to a UDF so you can keep all of the conditions straight.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up just doing this.  I count get the last part moved to get the results I wanted.   I really appreciate the help, I am going to start reviewing documents on UDF to see how that all works.

=IF(AND(G2="received", C2<>0), "pass", IF(AND(G2="exception", C2=0), "pass", IF(AND(G2="ordered", C2=0), "pass", IF(AND(G2="picked", C2=0), "pass", IF(AND(G2="shipped", C2<>0, TODAY()-X2<=1), "review", "fail")))))